# LoadDictation with SAPI

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I am able to create alternate dictation grammars using the dictation resource kit or directions given [here](http://www.mperfect.net/dicResKit/).  I am not able to load the new dictation topic with c++.  I am trying to modify the simpledict sample provided with the sapi5.1 sdk.  The following doesn't work.

```
 std::wstring stemp = s2ws("grammar:dictation#Genre");  
    LPCWSTR mygrammar = stemp.c_str();
    hr = m_cpDictationGrammar->LoadDictation(mygrammar, SPLO_STATIC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your new dictation language model is named "Genre",

```
hr = m_cpDictationGrammar->LoadDictation(L"Genre", SPLO_STATIC);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks it works.  My other issue was i had forgotten that i had renamed the directory with my "Genre" language model. As usual, human error.